# CLLocationManager reports same coordinate several times with different timestamp

Tags: ios, swift, coordinates, cllocationmanager, distance

I have an app (iOS 9, Xcode 7.3, Swift) that tracks users location and calculates distance driven based on that. The app has been in the store for 3 weeks now. Have about 5000 users and ONE user (that I know of) is reporting distance being (a lot) higher then the actual distance.

I've come to the conclusion that it's **very likely a problem (hardware maybe???) with his phone**. See below how I've come to this (preliminary) conclusion and why I'm sticking with it until other users start reporting the same thing **ór someone here can convince me that's its a problem in my code** 
(Please don't tell me it's a cached coordinate, because then the timestamp would be the same (wouldn't it?) and my code would filter it out)

This is my code inside the delegate:

```
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateToLocation newLocation: CLLocation, fromLocation oldLocation: CLLocation) {

    dispatch_async(processLocationUpdateQeue) { [unowned self] in
        guard newLocation != nil && newLocation.horizontalAccuracy >= 0 && newLocation.timestamp.isLaterThan(self.previousLocation?.timestamp) && newLocation.timestamp.isLaterThan(self.tripStartTime)  else {
            return
        }

        if self.previousLocation != nil {
            self.coveredDistanceInMeters = self.coveredDistanceInMeters + Float(newLocation.distanceFromLocation(self.previousLocation!))
        }
        self.previousLocation = newLocation

        // Some other stuff
    }
}
```

This user was kind enough to do some more testing. Also with other apps (by other developers). We found that it's not only my app, but every app that tracks distance through incoming coordinates has the same problem on his phone. Navigation apps like TomTom and Navigon do not have this problem on his phone but I'm guessing that's because they calculate traveled distance based on the calculated route and not the incoming coordinates.

I analysed the coordinates coming in on his device and found that the same coordinate sometimes comes in 7 times (each with different timestamp). Each following time the coordinate comes in it is IMMEDIATELY followed by a correct coordinate. Unfortunately I only log to the second so not sure how close this immediate is. Here are the details:

In this case the first 6 minutes of the trip are fine. No strange things happening.

After 6 minutes, coordinates sent by the GPS are coming in twice or sometimes even more than twice, but with a different timestamp. Here are some screenshots to illustrate:

[image]
Coordinate nr 144. First time it comes in. OK So Far.

[image]
A different coordinate comes in, further down the road. Although it strange that is't IMMEDIATELY after the previous one. Distance is still OK.

[image]
Then coordinate 144 comes in again (as 146), but with a different timestamp. So, it thinks you moved back from 145 (and counts the distance for it)

[image]
Another coordinate comes in. Further than nr 145. So, this is a correct coordinate. But it’s calculating the distance from 146 as that’s the previous coordinate. (In fact 146 should be ignored and distance from 145 should be calculated, which is closer)

[image]
Same coordinate comes in AGAIN… same thing happens.

Comment: Just FYI that delegate method was deprecated in iOS 6!  You should use `didUpdateLocations` and process the 1 or more locations that are delivered to this method.  I suggest you try with the newer delegate method and see if you still have the problem

Comment: @Paulw11 Thanks for pointing this out Paul. I'm actually using a framework that uses it's own delegate method to pass me the last location. Wanted to leave that out as I'm 100% sure it's not the framework. (Because I have an older (iOS6) app that does use the delegate in my question and same thing happens with that app on his phone. Also same problem on his phone with another tracking app from another developer. Can't be sure which delegate that one uses but it's an iOS8 app.